# Reading from a file error

Tags: c, file

This is a c program that read from a file and prints informaton based on "acc_num". But the problem is that it only accepts the first acc_num in the file
Why is that ? I wanted it to search throught the entire file for a specific acc_num.

```
 #include < stdio.h >
 #include < string.h >
 #include < conio.h >
 struct CUSTOMER {
char fname[50];
char lname[50];
char address[100];
char con_num[50];
char email[50];
char acc_num[999]; //account number 
  };

struct CUSTOMER information[999];
int main() {
FILE * fptr;
fptr = fopen("customers.dat", "r");
int i;
int x;
char acc[50];

for (x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
printf("Enter account number:");
scanf("%s", & acc);
getchar();

for (x = 0; x < 1; x++) {

  fscanf(fptr, " %s\n", information[x].acc_num);
  fscanf(fptr, " %s\n", information[x].fname);
  fscanf(fptr, " %s\n", information[x].lname);
  if (strcmp(information[x].acc_num, acc) == 0) {
    printf("%s%s%s", information[x].acc_num, information[x].fname, information[x].lname);
    getchar();
  }
 }
 }
  getch();
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Look at your "for" stop condition "x < 1". It will only run once.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%s", & acc);` doesn't work / is undefined behaviour and `acc` is never initialized (at best), and you cannot find the pattern in your file.

In the case of strings `scanf` needs a pointer/array of chars, and you already provide it with `acc`.

You have to do `scanf("%s", acc);`

Also, your inner loop goes up to `1`. It only reads one record! And once the file is read, there's no data to read anymore. You should open the file and scan through it every time and stop when you reach end of file.

Comment: You are fast, sir. :) 
Dear OP, your acc is uninitialized, and you compare it against a string. So you have to be cautious. I'll add that he's only looping once.. hence he gets only one result

Comment: thanks :) now I'm beginning to regret having answered. The code has a lot of problems, I'm not sure to be able to catch them all.

Comment: You've mentioned a lot of errors and there are more I guess. Fair enough for the +1 I've done. I abhor unindented code so I quit...